# How to solve JobBuilder deprecated in SpringBatch 5.1.1

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am using STS 3.2.3 and SpringBatch 5.1.1
When I build a batch job, I replace JobBuilderFactory with JobBuilder according to the 5.0 migration guide. But JobBuilder is also deplicated. How can I solve this issue?

I expect to solve the problem by beplacing JobBuilderFactory with JobBuilder, but JobBuilder is also deprecated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `JobBuilder` is not deprecated.